# Crash when reading /proc/net/ip_conntrack with netfilter accounting enabled

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, netfilter

Hoping someone might have an idea -

I've been exploring my home router which is running Linux 3.4.11-rt19. I enabled conntrack accounting using `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_acct` and have been looking at `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` as I browse to various websites.

My problem is that as I am loading a relatively heavy site with flash animations, graphics, ads etc., the `cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack` command will occasionally crash the router. This happens pretty frequently - I can easily crash the router within a minute or two.

The crash does not reproduce if I do not enable conntrack accounting.

I was looking at the netfilter code trying to spot potential race conditions or missing locks but came up empty. I also tried to examine the differences in netfilter code against later Linux versions without success.

Are there any ways for me to debug this? Or is this a known issue? By any chance is there a workaround that does not require me to re-implement this `proc` file in kernel mode?

Comment: Could you please attach a crash log? Is kernel backtrace the same for every crash?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't - when the router crashes I lose all access to it, and it then boots up with no record of the crash (at least, none that I could find). Maybe there's a way to control this, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: @MrCryo not sure you saw my reply since I didn't address it to you with "@'...

Comment: I added the answer as comment has length limit.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason of crashing is may be the low memory of the router as while processing your request while netfilter  accounting enabled , as it is not able to process the website containing flash etc.

As ,  a solution of this u can use custom made router based on full Linux support which u can install on a low end , scrap old PC or single board computers available in the market.

There are many Linux distros are available , some famous one are like

> **pfsense**

***strong text***

> **Smoothwall**

etc.

Comment: Thanks Pratik. One of my goals is load testing the router itself so I can't use replacements - I want to work with the router itself. There seems to be "plenty" of memory available, in router standards, and there are not that many open parallel connections (< 1000) so I wouldn't have thought the router is overloaded. Plus, it seems that this only happens when I look at the `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` file which to me strongly suggests a race condition in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

At first I'd try to disable reboot on panic:

```
echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic
```

Then I'd try to disable panic on oops and some other situations:

```
echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic_on_oops
echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic_on_stackoverflow
echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic_on_unrecovered_nmi
echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic_on_rcu_stall
echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic_on_warn
```

This could give you a chance to keep control your router over issue.

Also if your kernel has built-in netconsole driver or standalone netconsole module, you could setup logging kernel messages to another machine. Look at [Kernel Netconsole documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt) to find out how to configure it dynamically.

Anyway, the important step to solve/understand an issue is to get kernel log on crash.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting `/proc/sys/kernel/panic` to 0 did not allow me to connect to the router after the crash. I'm now trying to build `netconsole` for the router's CPU and kernel. This is proving to be more difficult than I thought, even though I already have the environment ready.